# How to tailor a CV for travel grant applications

Tags: computer-science, funding, cv, travel

Can anyone advise on how to tailor a CV for travel grant applications?

I've seen a number of computer science conferences and workshops where the application for travel grants consists of simply sending your CV.

Is there anything that one can do specifically for this type of application?

Comment: I'd suggest sending an academic version of your CV (that has all your publications and pedagogical activities listed)...

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, your CV is your CV, and it should list basically everything of scientific significance about you (unless you're so far along in your career that you can do an impressive "highlight" CV).  The main decision available to you is how you order and cluster these things.

Thus, if your CV is already ordered and grouped to put your best foot forward, scientifically, I don't think you need to do anything else in particular to tailor it for a travel grant application.  I certainly know that when I have been in the position of looking at student/early-career applications to decide on travel grants, the full package is generally small enough that it's easy to see the significant bits no matter how things are formatted.

Answer (score 1):

You should always try to tailor your CV to the opportunity you are applying for. You might want to consider a personal statement of two sentences that encapsulate who you are and why this travel grant is relevant for you. People tend to read the beginning of CVs and then skim. You want to make sure that the narrative makes sense, so don't include too much information and make sure that the information included is phrased so as to be relevant to the opportunity. Definitely include a page with all your publications and previous conference papers. In terms of conference travel grants, however, it's going to mainly depend on the paper proposal - how relevant the proposal is to the conference's main aims will determine how much the organizers want to help make sure you can attend.

Comment: _don't include too much information_ — **I strongly disagree.**  An academic CV (at least in the US) is always a *complete* formal list of academic accomplishments, including all publications, talks, awards, grants, teaching experience, and so on.

Comment: @JeffE: my academic CV does not include all my talks (though it did when I had given fewer talks). For people more senior than I am, I think it is extremely common that one's CV would include only a selection of talks (e.g. colloquiua, plenary lectures, etc.). Still, I agree with your overall point: it would be very strange if a CV included only some of the author's publications, for example.

Comment: A personal statement in your CV is a great idea: it could set you apart from other applicants by making it clear why you would benefit from being able to attend this conference, and why the conference would benefit from your presence.

Answer (score 0):

I think is the same as for job application - show the accomplished things but in a more direct way, not descriptive way e.g.
"I participated in the project X that was dealing with Y, we proposed Z that is modified algorithm ZZ." can be converted to 
"We/I developed new algorithm Z showed better performance compared to state-of-art. The algo applicable in this and that areas".